# Quick check of my data structure in Firebase database

Tags: data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, data-modeling

I'm quite new to firebase. I've been reading posts and watching some data-modelling tutorials about firebase. General advice is always:

> Save duplicated data in many places. This way reading is gonna be quick as query syntax is limited. Saving will be more expensive but it occurs rarely.

This point of view makes much sense, i can certenaily understand it. That being said, i'd like to ask you for a quick check to see if is the data structure that i want to use the proper one. I have a bit of experience with mongoDB which has DB references, not existing in firebase. It just feels weird to duplicate data that much. I guess it's SQL ancestry as well, but who knows.

I'm trying to create some sort of boilerplate for a future multi-user app. Prequisites:

- Each document has one author
- Each document can have multiple members
- Each user can be a mamber of unlimited number of documents
- Open documents are publicly accessible, private documents are accessible only by members

This is schematic representation of what i came up with. Three dots mean that siblings are possible.

```
users: {
    *userUID*: {
        uid: *userUID*
        name: User One
        bio: Lorem ipsum
        birthdate: 01-01-2000
        ownedDocuments: {
            *documentUID*: {
                uid: *documentUID*
                title: Document title
                coverImage: imageUrl
                status: private
                membersCount: 3
            }
            ...
        }
        documents: {
            *documentUID*: {
                uid: *documentUID*
                title: Document title
                coverImage: imageUrl
                status: private
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}

documents: {
    *documentUID* {
        uid: *documentUID*
        title: Document title
        coverImage: imageUrl
        status: private
        membersCount: 3
        author: {
            uid: *userUID*
            name: User One
        }
        members: {
            *userUID*
                uid: *userUID*
                name: User One
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

As i have said before - it feels wrong probably because of what i'm used to in SQL. So if this is (more or less) valid approach then i'll be happy to hear it. Of course if it's wrong, of there are any remarks / optimalisations / anything i'd love to read it.

Thank You

Comment: In NoSQL solutions you model the data for how your application uses it. That means that there is no single "correct" way to model data, as it depends on the use-cases of your app. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: That said: you're nesting documents under users, which in general is an anti-pattern in Firebase. Imagine trying to read a list of users with your current structure. Doing so will also read all documents for all users. Imagine the bandwidth that uses. So it's best to keep the documents for each user under a separate top-level collection, keyed by UID (just like the `/users` list).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for help! Now i think i get it. So i should create `users`, `documents` and `userdocuments`. That sounds to me a bit like mimicking sql joins on level of data structure. I didn't have time today, i'll think of a new structure and i'll update the question. Thank you again!